# How to predict sentiment of unseen text?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sentiment-analysis

Using scikit learn, I have trained my model but dont know how to use the model to predict new text passages. I have watched tons of tutorials but none of them go beyond training and testing. Below is the code Im using

```
data_source_url = "/path/to/file.csv"
airline_tweets = pd.read_csv(data_source_url)

features = airline_tweets.iloc[:, 10].values
labels = airline_tweets.iloc[:, 1].values

processed_features = []

    # I do some text processing here and then append the text to processed_features

        
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer = 'word', lowercase = False)
features = vectorizer.fit_transform(processed_features)
features_nd = features.toarray() # for easy usage

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test  = train_test_split(features_nd, labels, train_size=0.80, random_state=1234)

log_model = LogisticRegression()
log_model = log_model.fit(X=X_train, y=y_train)
    
predictions = log_model.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Where did `text_classifier` come from? You mean `log_model.predict(X_test)`?

Comment: yes you are right. I meant  log_model.predict(X_test)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you just need to follow the same step to transform your new dataset. Then, use your trained model to predict. It looks something like that:

```py
new_dataset = ...    # read your new dataset
new_processed_features = []
    # do the same text processing here

# Use the same vectorizer to transform your new dataset        
new_features = vectorizer.transform(new_processed_features)
new_features_nd = new_features.toarray() # for easy usage

# Use your trained model to predict new dataset
new_predictions = log_model.predict(new_features_nd)
```